# Series of IF STATEMENTS to determine a variable, JAVA

Tags: java

As it stands this is the code I am trying:

```
if(gear.isLeftHand())
    helix = (gear.getParentPair().beta());
else if (gear.isRightHand())
    helix = Math.PI - (gear.getParentPair().beta());
else if (gear.isSpur())
    helix = 0;
else 
    helix = 0;

double stepAng =  (thickness /radius) * helix;
```

However it is not working, this is because 'helix can not be resolved to a variable'

I am trying to get a value for stepAng depending upon whether the initial angle is left handed or right handed, therefore the value for 'helix' will be calculated from different formulas depending on this direction.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: **1)** Please don't indent like that. **2)** Where did you declare this `helix`?

Comment: You need to **declare** the variable at some point. Java isn't Python.

Comment: What error your are getting

Comment: where you have declared helix

Comment: Please just dont copy code, instead understand why you get this error otherwise today its helix tommorrow will be matrix :P

Comment: I didn't declare it. Now I have. No matrix tomorrow

Comment: haha our intension is not to make guilty but learn :) that whenever you get such error then see the scope...you will face same problem for variables in try/catch block too.

Answer (score 5):

You need to actually declare `helix`, and you can do away with two of your expressions if you initialize it to 0 (I'm assuming it's a `double` given that you make reference to `Math.PI`):

```
double helix = 0;
if (gear.isLeftHand()) {
    helix = (gear.getParentPair().beta());
} else if (gear.isRightHand()) {
    helix = Math.PI - (gear.getParentPair().beta());
}

double stepAng =  (thickness / radius) * helix;
```

Comment: Beat me to it. @amie, please note the use of nice indenting and curly braces that were added here. It makes the code so much more readable!

Answer (score 2):

You may have declared **helix** outside of the scope of usage or didn't declare at all.

```
double helix = 0;

// The rest of the code follows
```

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `helix` before the `if` statement. When you try to assign `stepAng`, `helix` is out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting compile error that "Cannot resolve variable XXX"(helix in your case), then you need to define it in scope which is accessible at all place, here may be starting of method or your class instance variable depending on your need.

First way:

```
  public double getArea(){
    double helix=0.0;
    if(cond){ 
        helix=//some code
    }else{
        helix=//some code
    }
       // some code with helix
  }
```

Second way:

```
 public class AreaCalculator(){
   //highest scope based on requirement.
   private double helix;

   public double getArea(){
      double helix=0.0;
      if(cond){ 
         helix=//some code
      }else{
         helix=//some code
      }
      // some code with helix
   }//method
 }//class
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do like this:

```
else if (gear.isSpur())
    helix = 0;
else 
    helix = 0
```

you can just do:

```
double helix = 0;
if (gear.isLeftHand()) {
    helix = (gear.getParentPair().beta());
} else if (gear.isRightHand()) {
    helix = Math.PI - (gear.getParentPair().beta());
}


double stepAng =  (thickness / radius) * helix;
```